# What does "'module' object is not subscriptable" mean in the context of this code?

Tags: python

Running test.py gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    Map = Parser.Map(os.path[0] + "\\start.wmap")
TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable
```

### Parser.py

```
import configparser
def StringIsNumber(String):
    try:
        int(String)
    except:
        return False
    return True
class Map:
    Parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
    MapURL = ""
    def __init__(self, Map):
        self.Parser.read(Map)
        self.MapURL = Map
    def TileTypes(self):
        #All numerical sections can be assumed to be tiles
        return [n for n in self.Parser.sections() if StringIsNumber(n)]
```

### test.py

```
import Parser
import os
Map = Parser.Map(os.path[0] + "\\start.wmap")
print(Map.TileTypes())
```

Comment: Oops! I was using os.path instead of sys.path! Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) is a module and you are using it as a list i think you're looking for [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path).

Answer (score 2):

That you can't get its properties using key/index lookup like `something[property]`

Answer (score 1):

You try to subscript os.path, which is a module. Subscripting means you use square brackets upon an object. That is legal for e.g. a dict object, but not for a module.

The error is in `os.path[...]`

Comment: Ah! I was using os.path instead of sys.path! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`os.path` is a module. It's unclear what you think `os.path[0]` is going to do for you, since it's not an iterable and has no 0th element.